# SwiftUI passing TabView binding variable around in global EnvironmentObject

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-tabview, swiftui-navigationstack

I've got a SwiftUI issue that only surfaces in a complex scenario.

My application has a `TabView` near the top  of the view structure. There are 5 tabs in total. Tab 1 and 5 are pretty simple `ScrollView` type views called `Home` and `Account`. Tabs 2,3,4 are `NavigationStack { List {...} }` type views called `Pending` `Active` `Inactive` respectively.

The idea of the app is that a request will be sent to the user and show up in the `Pending` list first (say `requestId = 123`). If the user views that `NavigationLink` item and accepts the request, then I'll update the server (which will move request `123` from the `Pending` list and place it in the `Active` list) then I'll query the server for the new lists and update my global data (which I'd like to store as an EnvironmentObject), then I'd like to re-navigate the user up out of the `Pending-NavigationLink-123` and over to the `Active` tab and select the same `NavigationLink` for request `123` that they were just in.

All of this works fine except for if the user were to (for some reason) navigate back to the `Pending` tab. If the user does go back to the `Pending` tab then there'd be an issue because request `123` was just moved to the `Active` tab. So I was the user to always be placed at the ROOT of the NavigationStack when the user changes tabs.

So what I did was, bind my `NavigationStack` to a `navigationPath: [Int]` variable for these three tabs that I would reset when I left the tab in the `onDisappear` method, so that if a user left a tab and came back to it then they'd wind up back at the root of the `NavigationStack`. This  means I now have 4 state variables to control 1) what tab I'm in and 2) what request is being displayed in those tabs.

To add complexity... I also have an AppDelegate that will be receiving Apple Push Notifications. These notifications will have a `RequestId` associated with them so that if the user taps the push notification banner I can redirect the user to the correct tab and select for them the correct request to display.

All of this complexity means I'd like to place all 4 of these State variables into a GlobalData class and just pass it around the application as an EnvironmentObject. But when I do that I get undesired behavior

here is my minimum working example to show the problem:

```
enum Tabs: String {
    case Home
    case Pending
    case Active
    case Inactive
    case Account
}

class GlobData: ObservableObject {
    struct Lists {
        var pendingList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        var activeList = [10, 11, 12]
        var inactiveList = [20, 21, 22]
        func forTab(_ tab: Tabs) -> [Int] {
            return tab == .Pending ? pendingList : (tab == .Active ? activeList : inactiveList)
        }
    }
    @Published var lists: Lists = Lists()
    @Published var destinationId: Int? = nil
    @Published var selectedTab: Tabs = .Pending      // **** comment this to make the code work
}

@main
struct PilotAppApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
//    @State var selectedTab: Tabs = .Pending        // **** uncomment this to make the code work
    @State var navigationPathOne: [Int] = []
    @State var navigationPathTwo: [Int] = []
    @State var navigationPathThree: [Int] = []
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView1(
//                selectedTab: $selectedTab,         // **** uncomment this to make the code work
                navigationPathOne: $navigationPathOne,
                navigationPathTwo: $navigationPathTwo,
                navigationPathThree: $navigationPathThree)
            .environmentObject(GlobData())
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView1: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var globData: GlobData
    
//    @Binding var selectedTab: Tabs                 // **** uncomment this to make the code work
    @Binding var navigationPathOne: [Int]
    @Binding var navigationPathTwo: [Int]
    @Binding var navigationPathThree: [Int]
    
    var body: some View {
//        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {         // **** uncomment this to make the code work
        TabView(selection: $globData.selectedTab) {  // **** comment this to make the code work
            NavStackView(
                thisTab: Tabs.Pending,
//                selectedTab: $selectedTab,         // **** uncomment this to make the code work
                navigationPath: $navigationPathOne
            )
            .tabItem {
                Label("Pending", systemImage: "house")
            }
            .tag(Tabs.Pending)

            NavStackView(
                thisTab: Tabs.Active,
//                selectedTab: $selectedTab,         // **** uncomment this to make the code work
                navigationPath: $navigationPathTwo
            )
            .tabItem {
                Label("Active", systemImage: "house")
            }
            .tag(Tabs.Active)
            
            NavStackView(
                thisTab: Tabs.Inactive,
//                selectedTab: $selectedTab,         // **** uncomment this to make the code work
                navigationPath: $navigationPathThree
            )
            .tabItem {
                Label("Inactive", systemImage: "house")
            }
            .tag(Tabs.Inactive)
        }
    }
}
struct NavStackView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var globData: GlobData
    
    let thisTab: Tabs
//    @Binding var selectedTab: Tabs                 // **** uncomment this to make the code work
    @Binding var navigationPath: [Int]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navigationPath) {
            List {
                ForEach(globData.lists.forTab(thisTab), id: \.self) { id in
                    NavigationLink(value: id) {
                        Text("\(id)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle(thisTab.rawValue)
            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { id in
                NavLinkContent(
                    id: id,
                    thisTab: thisTab,
//                    selectedTab: $selectedTab,     // **** uncomment this to make the code work
                    navigationPath: $navigationPath
                )
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            print("\nNavStackView OnAppear: \(thisTab)")
        }
        .task {
            print("NavStackView Task: \(thisTab)")
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let destinationId = globData.destinationId {
                    if globData.lists.forTab(thisTab).contains(destinationId) {
                        navigationPath = [destinationId]
                    }
                    globData.destinationId = nil
                }
            }
        }
        .onDisappear() {
            print("NavStackView OnDisappear: \(thisTab)")
            // ******************************************************************** //
            // ** This is where I reset the navigation path when I leave the tab ** //
            // ******************************************************************** //
            navigationPath = []
        }
    }
}
struct NavLinkContent: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var globData: GlobData
    
    let id: Int
    let thisTab: Tabs
//    @Binding var selectedTab: Tabs                 // **** uncomment this to make the code work
    @Binding var navigationPath: [Int]
    
    func goToId(_ id: Int) {
        if id == self.id {
            return
        } else if globData.lists.forTab(thisTab).contains(id) {
            navigationPath = [id]
        } else if globData.lists.pendingList.contains(id) {
            globData.destinationId = id
//            selectedTab = .Pending                 // **** uncomment this to make the code work
            globData.selectedTab = .Pending          // **** comment this to make the code work
        } else if globData.lists.activeList.contains(id) {
            globData.destinationId = id
//            selectedTab = .Active                  // **** uncomment this to make the code work
            globData.selectedTab = .Active           // **** comment this to make the code work
        } else if globData.lists.inactiveList.contains(id) {
            globData.destinationId = id
//            selectedTab = .Inactive                  // **** uncomment this to make the code work
            globData.selectedTab = .Inactive           // **** comment this to make the code work
        } else {
            navigationPath = []
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("NavLinkContent(\(id))")
            ForEach(globData.lists.pendingList, id: \.self) { id in
                Button("Go To: \(id)") {
                    goToId(id)
                }
            }
            ForEach(globData.lists.activeList, id: \.self) { id in
                Button("Go To: \(id)") {
                    goToId(id)
                }
            }
            ForEach(globData.lists.inactiveList, id: \.self) { id in
                Button("Go To: \(id)") {
                    goToId(id)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            print("\n        NavLinkContent OnAppear(\(thisTab))(\(id))")
        }
        .task {
            print("        NavLinkContent Task(\(thisTab))(\(id))")
        }
        .onDisappear() {
            print("        NavLinkContent OnDisappear(\(thisTab))(\(id))")
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the steps to show the issue

1. starting from the `Pending` tab at app start
2. select one of the navigation links, say number `4`
3. from here select one of the buttons to go to an id in another tab, say number `10` which will send you to the `Active` tab and it will select the navigation link for id `10`
4. from here go back to the `Pending` tab
5. now on the surface everything may have seemed fine because you did end up back at the Root of the `Pending` tab...

   - But... if you look at the debug print statements you should see that when you navigated back to the `Pending` tab it ended up printing `NavLinkContent OnAppear(Pending)(4)` and `NavLinkContent OnDisappear(Pending)(4)` and `NavLinkContent Task(Pending)(4)`...
   - So what happened? when I left the `Pending` tab I set the `NavigationPath = []` so when I came back it should have known to just put me at the root. Why did it try to open `id = 4`?
   - What's even worse is the `NavLinkContent Task(Pending)(4)` print. This means that the httprequests would end up running to get the content to fill that view even if the view isn't really visible

Here's what is printed out that I DON't want:

```
                                        -- app start
NavStackView OnAppear: Pending
NavStackView Task: Pending
                                        -- clicking nav link 4
    NavLinkContent OnAppear(Pending)(4)
    NavLinkContent Task(Pending)(4)
                                        -- clicking go to 10
NavStackView OnAppear: Active
    NavLinkContent OnDisappear(Pending)(4)
NavStackView OnDisappear: Pending
NavStackView Task: Active

    NavLinkContent OnAppear(Active)(10)
    NavLinkContent Task(Active)(10)
                                        -- clicking Pending tab
    NavLinkContent OnAppear(Pending)(4)      -- this should not print

NavStackView OnAppear: Pending
    NavLinkContent OnDisappear(Active)(10)
NavStackView OnDisappear: Active
    NavLinkContent OnDisappear(Pending)(4)   -- this should not print
    NavLinkContent Task(Pending)(4)          -- this should not print
NavStackView Task: Pending
```

If you take the supplied code and toggle where I've commented sections then I get the expected result. This will move the `selectedTab` variable out of the GlobalData class and make it so its has to be passed through every view... which sucks and isn't what I want... but it works...

Here's what's printed out that is correct:

```
                                      -- app start
NavStackView OnAppear: Pending
NavStackView Task: Pending
                                      -- clicking nav link 4
    NavLinkContent OnAppear(Pending)(4)
    NavLinkContent Task(Pending)(4)
                                      -- clicking go to 10
NavStackView OnAppear: Active
    NavLinkContent OnDisappear(Pending)(4)
NavStackView OnDisappear: Pending
NavStackView Task: Active

    NavLinkContent OnAppear(Active)(10)
    NavLinkContent Task(Active)(10)
                                      -- clicking Pending
NavStackView OnAppear: Pending
    NavLinkContent OnDisappear(Active)(10)
NavStackView OnDisappear: Active
NavStackView Task: Pending
```

What I'm really looking for:

1. I'd like these State variables to all live in a GlobalData class that's passed around (It's very annoying to have to explicitly pass each State variable through every view)
2. I need to find a way to get this GlobalData class into my AppDelegate as well so that it can be used when I receive Apple Push Notifications

Sorry for the large novel... but this issue can only be scene in a complex scenario...

Thanks for any help!

**Update**

I'm wondering if there's something wrong with my work phone. I've got a work iPhone13(iOS 16.2) and a personal iPhone11(iOS 16.1). I've been developing on my work phone (and that's where I've experienced the issues described above). So I just tested my project on my personal phone... and didn't see the issue... I then pulled up the simulator (which I don't normally use, I just prefer to be on the real device) set to an iPhone13(iOS 16.2) and it didn't have the issue...

Do you think this is just my phone? a bug to report to apple?

Comment: So why are you using `@State` properties?  Why aren't they published properties of your `GlobData`?  One method to get it to your app delegate is to use a singleton, or you can just set it as a property on your `appDelegate` in your app struct

Comment: When ‘selectedTab’ is a ‘@Published’ property of GlobalData that’s when I have issues

Comment: Using your code as-is from your question I get the output you say you want - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/f8eee6f35b979115ce96a67fd3edebd1